# How to construct a custom class path in Maven2

Tags: java, maven-2, ant, maven-plugin

I'm executing an ant task inside my maven pom files to code generation purposes. (the code-generation tool is wsdl2java). during the process I fork new java process and pass the class path along with wsdl.

this works fine in the unix environment. but windows gives error saying ;

```
CreateProcess error=87, The parameter is incorrect.
```

this is because I'm passing the parameter maven.dependency.classpath as the classpath of the codegen tool. I have figured out that if there is a way to construct my custom classpath, using maven, that would solve my problem. (instead of giving a classpath includes all the jars in the maven repo).

`maven-dependency-pluing:build-path` goal seems to be promising, but i can specify the exact jars i want to include in my new classpath.

- i have to include the class path variable in a root, pom so that other modules can use it.(lots of them)
- I could find a way with maven-dependency-plugin:copy goal. but that it is a performance hit.

appreciate any help.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a way to build a classPath using dependency or any other maven plugin. The only option was to create a custom classPath and use it while java execution.

```
<path id="custom.classpath">
  <pathelement location="location of the jar file"/>
</path>
```

And you refer the constructed classpath later in the java process execution.

```
<java className = "org.myClass">
     <classpath refid="custom.classpath"/>
</java>
```

Hope this helps.